# Jquery ajax basic authentification service, Error: appear alert window

Tags: jquery, ajax, rest, web-services

I'm making a service with Jquery $.ajax, when call the service appear a window alert.

Service information:

- Service type: REST Basic authentication
- Estructure: Application/JSON
- Url:https://osb.urosario.edu.co/uxxi-URO/WsFotografias/proxy/AdministradorFotografiasJsonPS/fotos/consultar
- User: Admin
- Password: admin
- Parameter  JSON example:    {"identificacion":["98122811999"]}

[image]

Code javascript:

```
  var markers = {}; //create obj
    var markersss_array = []
    markersss_array.push("1019035955");
    //more datas push in array
    markers["identificacion"] = markersss_array; //pass aray to json object

    var markersConvertido = JSON.stringify(markers);
    var username = "Admin";
    var password = "admin";    

 $.ajax
      ({
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://osb.urosario.edu.co/uxxi-URO/WsFotografias/proxy/AdministradorFotografiasJsonPS/fotos/consultar",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic "
            + btoa(username + ":" + password));
        },          
        crossDomain: true,  
        data: markersConvertido,
       success: function (data) {
            alert(data); 
        },
        error: function ( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(errorThrown);
            // alert(errorThrown);
        }
    });
```

Comment: You cannot set auth headers in jsonp requests as they do not use xhr or fetch. The only other alternative I know of is deprecated, which is having the credentials in the url.

Comment: thanks @Musa how to do credentials in the url?

Comment: `https://username:password@sub.domain.tld`, but it doesn't work so...